# Flink streaming - Calculate average of different fields of an Avro object in a time window

Tags: java, avro, flink-streaming

Please, this is the first time that I write a flink job and I need help. The goal of the job is to calculate the average of different fields of an avro object. The avro schema that I use to parse json messages that come from an ActiveMQ queue is the following:

```
[
   {
      "type":"record",
      "name":"SensorDataAnnotation",
      "namespace":"zzz",
      "fields":[
         {"name":"meas","type":["null","string"]},
         {"name":"prefix","type":["null","string"]}
      ]
   },
   {
      "namespace":"zzz",
      "name":"SensorDataList",
      "type":"record",
      "fields":[
         {"name":"SensorDataListContainer",
          "type":{"name":"SensorDataListContainer","type":"array","namespace":"zzz",
            "items":{"type":"record","name":"SensorData","namespace":"zzz",
                  "fields":[
                     {"name":"prkey","type":"int"},
                     {"name":"prkeyannotation","type":["null","SensorDataAnnotation"]},
                     {"name":"value1","type":["null","double"]},
                     {"name":"value1annotation","type":["null","SensorDataAnnotation"]},
                     {"name":"value2","type":["null","double"]},
                     {"name":"value2annotation","type":["null","SensorDataAnnotation"]},
                     {"name":"value3","type":["null","int"]},
                     {"name":"value3annotation","type":["null","SensorDataAnnotation"]}
  }
]
```

This is the flink job that I tried to write:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<SensorData> messages = env.addSource(new StreamSource());

        DataStream<Double> counts = messages
                .map(new MapFunction<SensorData, Double>() {
                    @Override
                    public Double map(SensorData arg0) throws Exception {

                        return arg0.getValue1();

                    }
                })
                .timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(10), Time.seconds(5))
                .apply(new Avg());

        counts.print();
        env.execute("ActiveMQ Streaming Job");
```

with the StreamSource and Avg classes:

**StreamSource**

```
class StreamSource extends RichSourceFunction<SensorData> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StreamSource.class);

    private transient volatile boolean running;

    private transient MessageConsumer consumer;
    private transient Connection connection;

    private void init() throws JMSException {
        // Create a ConnectionFactory
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

        // Create a Connection
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        // Create a Session
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("input");

        // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
        consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

    }


    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        running = true;
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<SensorData> ctx) {
        // this source never completes

        while (running) {

            try {
                // Wait for a message
                Message message = consumer.receive(1000);
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    String text = textMessage.getText();
                    try {
                        byte[] avroDesObj = jsonToAvro(text, SensorData.SCHEMA$.toString());
                        DatumReader<SensorData> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<SensorData>(SensorData.SCHEMA$);
                        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(avroDesObj, null);
                        SensorData data = reader.read(null, decoder);
                        ctx.collect(data);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    LOG.error("Don't know what to do .. or no message");
                }
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                running = false;
            }
        }
        try {
            close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {

        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Closing");
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing ActiveMQ connection ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Avg**

```
public static class Avg implements AllWindowFunction<Double,Double, TimeWindow> {
                @Override
                public void apply(TimeWindow window, Iterable<Double> values, Collector<Double> out) throws Exception {
                    double sum = 0.0;
                    int count = 0;
                    for(Double value : values) {
                        sum += value.doubleValue();
                        count++;
                    }
                    Double avg = values.iterator().next();
                    avg = sum / count;
                    out.collect(avg);

                }
            }
```

When I launch the exported jar of this job in the flink dashboard, it does not start and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thank You.

Comment: The first thing you'd want to do is to try running it locally, from your IDE (better) or via a local Flink cluster (one that you start with `<flink install>/bin/start-local.sh`). Also, when asking questions about Flink, it's very useful to include the version of Flink you're using. Also, never just print the stack trace in catch block (as you're doing above)...you typically want to ensure it gets bubbled up.

Comment: Thank you. I am using flink 1.4.0. I simplified the job, making it only print messages it gets from the queue. I tried to run the job from eclipse but when I launch it, it terminates instantly, while if I upload it in flink, it starts but does not print anything. [Here](https://pastebin.com/LVXaRQnG) is the log from the job manager and [here](https://pastebin.com/5NUkEsaa) the job I am referring now. I have another program that constantly sends messages to the queue and I can also see in the ActiveMQ dashboard that 1 consumer is active, I guess it's flink job.

Comment: What's your cluster configuration? I see messages in the Job Manager log like: `Limiting managed memory to 0.7 of the currently free heap space (458 MB), memory will be allocated lazily.` I also see only one TaskManager slot. Looks like you're trying to run this on your Windows machine.

Comment: The Task Manager log file is often more useful than the Job Manager log file.

Comment: I ran the job again, checked the task manager stdout and found the Json messages printed. Then I tried to make it prints only the results of the map function and it worked! Finally I tried to run the entire Job and now i can see printed in the task manager stdout the average of the field of the avro object. I have another question now: why if I run this job from eclipse it terminates instantly? Should I use a while true in the print statement? I launch it without the env.execute(). Thank you for your patience and for your advices.